# How do I log out of superuser.com?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Seems like such a basic function, but I have searched (and searched!) superuser.com and cannot find any way to log out.

Or should I just close the browser and clear my cookies?

I am having trouble posting this basic question because the system says it does not meet "quality standards."

Answer (score 3):

On the top right corner, click the three lines and there is an option there.

[image]